# Where to download android for galaxy S5 (G900FZHU1ANE3)?

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s-5, downloading

I have problem with my android. Even if I do factory reset. I decide to install another copy of android.

My phone is samsung galaxy S5. Even though finding android for US models is easy ([link](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads)), my phone model is `G900FZHU1ANE3` from Hong Kong and I could not find any android file to download.

Could any one please help he to know where I could download the correct version of android?

Comment: Please see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 2):

The newest available Image ( Android 5.0 ) for your Sm-G900F Samsung Galaxy s5 is available on [**sammobile**](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/54667/G900FZHU1BOH3_G900FZZH1BOH3_TGY/).

Look at the instructions for flashing on this site:

```
Extract (unzip) the firmware file
Download Odin v3.10.7
Extract Odin ZIP file
Open Odin v3.10.7
Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked
Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes
```

Comment: Please do not answer completely off-topic questions since it tend to encourage users to ask such off-topic content again. See [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic and off-topic.